# How to use java variable to insert values to mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi i am trying to insert the values in to mysql table. i am trying this code.
i have assigned values to variable and i want to pass that variable to that insert statement.
 Is this correct?

```
code
    int tspent = "1";
    String pid = "trng";
    String tid = "2.3.4";
    String rid = "tup";
    String des = " polish my shoes!";

    INSERT INTO `time_entry`(pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE ('"+pid+"','"+tid+"','"+rid+"',"+tspent+",'"+des+"');
```

here is what i have tried, but i am not able to insert values

```
try
       {
           conn=DBMgr.openConnection();     
           String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO `time_entry`(pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE ('"+pid+"','"+tid+"','"+rid+"',"+tspent+",'"+des+"');";
           st = conn.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery); 
       }
```

Comment: "Java execute SQL" returns a huge number of hits :)

Comment: did u got any exception

Comment: @Sam... It's pretty obvious that this code is not even going to compile.

Comment: change executeQuery to executeUpdate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this,

```
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    String uname="username";
    String pass="password";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection c=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
    Statement s=c.createStatement();
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `time_entry`(pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE ('"+pid+"','"+tid+"','"+rid+"',"+tspent+",'"+des+"')");
```

Comment: you take all string. Is it workable for integer datatype variable?

Comment: Do **not** use `('"+pid+"','"+tid+"','"+rid+"',"+tspent+",'"+des+"')`, it is an open door for SQL Injection

Answer (score 21):

You should use `executeUpdate()` method whenever your query is an *SQL Data Manipulation Language* statement. Also, your current query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should use `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `time_entry`(pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");\
```

Then set the variables at those index:

```
pstmt.setString(1, pid);
// Similarly for the remaining 4 

// And then do an executeUpdate
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and set the values using its *setXXX()* methods.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `time_entry`
        (pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE 
        (?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, pid );
pstmt.setString(2, tid);
pstmt.setString(3, rid);
pstmt.setInt(4, tspent);
pstmt.setString(5,des );
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;  
class Adbs1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rk","root","@dmin");  
//here rk is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values('rk11','Irfan')");
 // stmt.executeUpdate("delete from  emp where eid ='rk4'");
//stmt.executeUpdate("update emp set ename='sallu bhai' where eid='rk5'");

 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
   while(rs.next())  
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));  

con.close();  
      }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```