# Java SQL Query not working with Insert?

Tags: java, sql

Why is this not adding more data into the Table? what is wrong with the code/query? The database is connected and works with Select * ...
but when i try to use Insert into, it gives the error shown below, why is that? how can i correct this error?

```
 public void RegisterNewUser(String username, String password, String firstname, String surname, String dateOfBirth, int currentWeight) {

    //This code will connect the database to the java program

    Connection myconObj = null; //allows to connect to database
    Statement mystatObj = null; // create statement (Execute queries)
    ResultSet myresObj = null; // get result
    ResultSetMetaData mymeta = null;

    try {

        String query = "INSERT INTO JACOVANSTRYP.MAINUSERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, CURRENTWEIGHTKG, ACTIVEPOINTS) VALUES(\"" + username + "\", \"" + password + "\", \"" + firstname + "\", \"" + surname + "\",\"" + dateOfBirth + "\", \"" + currentWeight + "0 )";

        myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MainUserData", "jacovanstryp", "Eduplex1234");
        mystatObj = myconObj.createStatement();
        Statement add = myconObj.createStatement();
        add.executeUpdate(query);
        mymeta = myresObj.getMetaData();





        System.out.println("User Successfuly created");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the error message its giving, i have tried to do this without the values that it gets from another class, and it still gives the same error even if the query is written in a plane string without external values.

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed. 
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.vanstryp.backend.commonMethods.RegisterNewUser(commonMethods.java:143)
    at com.vanstryp.GUI.Secure.Register.jButton1ActionPerformed(Register.java:389)
    at com.vanstryp.GUI.Secure.Register.access$400(Register.java:6)
    at com.vanstryp.GUI.Secure.Register$4.actionPerformed(Register.java:139)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ERROR 42X80: VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed. 
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLIMMreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readExecuteImmediate_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Rewrite using parameters

Comment: try using prepared statement and use Execute query instead of Update

Comment: It says executeQuery method can not be used for update.

Comment: You're missing a comma before last zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more wrong with the chosen approach than the query itself. I've rewritten your code to use the PreparedStatement functionality:

```
public void RegisterNewUser(String username, String password, String firstname, String surname, String dateOfBirth, int currentWeight) {

    //This code will connect the database to the java program

    Connection myconObj = null; //allows to connect to database
    ResultSet myresObj = null; // get result
    ResultSetMetaData mymeta = null;

    try {

        String query = "INSERT INTO JACOVANSTRYP.MAINUSERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, CURRENTWEIGHTKG, ACTIVEPOINTS) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MainUserData", "jacovanstryp", "Eduplex1234");
        PreparedStatement add = myconObj.prepareStatement(query);
        add.setString(1, username);
        add.setString(2, password);
        add.setString(3, firstname);
        add.setString(4, lastname);
        add.setString(5, dateOfBirth); // might need setDate() depending on your table structure
        add.setString(6, currentWeight);
        add.setString(7, "0");
        add.executeUpdate();
        mymeta = myresObj.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("User Successfuly created");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps...

@MarkRotteveel wants an explanation as to what is wrong with OPs code. Really, nothing in particular. It may work, but needs more care in construction. Also, constructing SQL as OPs doing opens him up to injection attacks. Again, not an issue for hobby projects, but in a professional context, you don't want to write code open to SQL injection.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what is wrong with the original approach.

Comment: mystatObj = myconObj.createStatement(); This line says it needs to cast PreparedStatement to it " mystatObj = (PreparedStatement) myconObj.createStatement();" When i do that, it returns this error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.PreparedStatement" Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, @jaco, just nix the mystatObj line

Comment: @MarkRotteveel was that in line with what you would have liked?

Comment: I wouldn't have started it with _"Really, nothing in particular."_, as the SQL injection in the original code is a gaping security bug. And I wouldn't have mentioned that it is _"not an issue for hobby projects"_, because habits and techniques learned in hobby projects are usually also applied without thinking in a professional context.

Answer (score 0):

You insert 6 paramenters for a 7 parameters query(check your last zero).
This is how you should do it:

```
  "INSERT INTO JACOVANSTRYP.MAINUSERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, CURRENTWEIGHTKG, ACTIVEPOINTS) VALUES(param1, param2, etc)"
```

Reference:
[How to use java variable to insert values to mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207088/how-to-use-java-variable-to-insert-values-to-mysql-table)

So try something like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO JACOVANSTRYP.MAINUSERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, CURRENTWEIGHTKG, ACTIVEPOINTS) VALUES(\"" + username + "\", \"" + password + "\", \"" + firstname + "\", \"" + surname + "\",\"" + dateOfBirth + "\", \"" + currentWeight + ",0 )";
```

Comment: -1 For not suggesting using prepared statements, but instead promoting the unsafe approach that keeps the code open to SQL injection, and the fact your suggestion doesn't even work, as the original problem is with the use of a double quote (which is for quoting object names) instead of single quotes (for literals).